# Fixed header and footer, with scrollable sidebar inside 1fr CSS grid region

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout for a webapp, with a fixed-size header and footer (defined with `rem` units), and an expandable center row (defined as `1fr`) that contains two sidebars and a central content area. The outer grid container is defined with a width and height to fill up the viewport (`100vw/vh`). I want the center row to take up all the space between the header and footer, and for any overflow to scroll, rather than to expand the height of the page.

I've tried various possible solutions, including using `overflow-y:scroll`, but nothing seems to work. The extra content makes the page longer, rather than making the region scrollable.

I don't want to use a fixed size for the center row, because I want it to expand to fit arbitrarily large screens.

Here's a fairly minimal example of my layout:

https://codepen.io/Shepazu/pen/EwePgB

(Please note that the nested areas in the HTML and CSS are intentional, so any solution should be CSS only, and shouldn't change the HTML markup.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://codepen.io/solbreslin/pen/pWOybz

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fixed height of header and footer is 100px, then give the style to the content area:

```
.center-row {
max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good start! It doesn't seem to work for me right away, possibly because of the nested grids, but I'll keep playing with the idea of using `calc` and `max-height`, and I'll let you know if that solves it. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me! (probably because my sticky header was not part of the same grid element, just the main body and the footer were.) Thanks.